# Is this Hibernate method very inefficient?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, performance, hibernate

This function is a piece of a Hibernate program I am writing to do some back-end bulk processing for a university financial system. It gets called several hundred thousand times when the program executes, and these calls are the single biggest time-sink in the program. For the moment I cannot think of a plausible way to call it less often.

This function takes a fiscal year pay period ("fypper") and a week in that period as arguments, and returns a construct ("AidYearTerm") that stores the year, semester, and term that the pay period week falls in.

```
public  AidYearTerm FypperTermInfo (String fypper, String week) {

    sfa_fws_calendar aidYear = new sfa_fws_calendar();      

    TypedQuery<sfa_fws_calendar> query = manager.createQuery("FROM sfa_fws_calendar cal "
            + "WHERE cal.id.fypper = ?1 AND cal.id.week_num = ?2",sfa_fws_calendar.class);
    query.setParameter(1, fypper);
    query.setParameter(2, week);

    List<sfa_fws_calendar> aidYearList = query.getResultList();

    if(!aidYearList.isEmpty()) {
        aidYear = query.getSingleResult();
    }
    else {
        aidYear.setFWS_AID_YR("9999");
        aidYear.setSEM("NOTSET");
        aidYear.setTERM("NOTSET");
        ErrorOut("Could not find term info for "+fypper);
    }
    DebugOut("found aid year "+aidYear.getFWS_AID_YR()+", term "+aidYear.getTERM());

    AidYearTerm aidYearTerm = new AidYearTerm(aidYear.getFWS_AID_YR(),aidYear.getTERM(),aidYear.getSEM()); 
    return aidYearTerm;

}
```

Is there something I can do to make this simpler/faster?

Comment: "gets called several hundred thousand times" -- A database query, executed hundreds of thousands of times? Wouldn't be surprised if there's not much to improve except vastly reducing this number.

Comment: By the way, how many combinations of year and week are there in your database? - If it's not millions, which I assume it isn't, it should be really easy to read them once, store them in a `HashMap` for example, and then operate on this cached data.

Comment: There are about 11,000 combinations. After storing them in a hashmap and referring to that instead of re-querying, a process that used to take two hours now takes about fifteen minutes. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'll add the approach to my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance:

```
List<sfa_fws_calendar> aidYearList = query.getResultList();

if(!aidYearList.isEmpty()) {
    aidYear = query.getSingleResult(); // <========= DON'T!!!!!
}
```

`Query.getSingleResult()` runs the same query again!

Use:

```
List<sfa_fws_calendar> aidYearList = query.getResultList();

if(!aidYearList.isEmpty()) {
    aidYear = aidYearList.get(0);
}
```

Edit:

Assuming you don't have millions of records keyed by year and week, it seems feasible to read all required data from `sfa_fws_calendar` into memory only once, for example into a `Map`, to subsequently avoid thousands of round trips to the DB.

Note that, because `fypper` and `week` actually form a (string) composite key, you could build a single `Map<String, AidYearTerm>`, where the keys could be, for example, `year + "_" + week`. Then your `FypperTermInfo (String fypper, String week)` would just `return aidYearCacheMap.get(fypper + "_" + week);` and voilà :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most obvious optimisation would be something like:

```
static final TypedQuery<sfa_fws_calendar> query = manager.createQuery("FROM sfa_fws_calendar cal "
        + "WHERE cal.id.fypper = ?1 AND cal.id.week_num = ?2", sfa_fws_calendar.class);

public AidYearTerm FypperTermInfo(String fypper, String week) {

    //...
    query.setParameter(1, fypper);
    query.setParameter(2, week);

    List<sfa_fws_calendar> aidYearList = query.getResultList();
```

Not sure of the overhead of calling `createQuery` but this would certainly only get that to happen once.

After that - if everything still runs at a crawl (and this is likely) you could consider some form of cacheing (perhaps [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/)) but that would only be effective if there were a comparatively small number of `fypper|week` combinations.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a pretty straightforward select, so I think this may be more of an issue around making sure Oracle runs it efficiently (especially since it's run many thousands of times per day). What kind of explain plan do you see for this query? Are there any full table scans?  You may need to index sfa_fws_calendar table, or if there are already indices in place, alter the appropriate index and recompute the index statistics.

For example, something like this might help update an existing index called index_name:

```sql
ALTER INDEX index_name REBUILD COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```